# How to set Windows Update to download, install updates then shut down?

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, windows-update

For a Windows 8.1 VM that is used only sporadically, I want to have the ability to select updates to install, then instruct the system to install those updates and once done shut down.

Windows Update is set to "Download updates but let me choose whether to install them". However, since the machine isn't on for very long at a time, there is rarely enough time for Windows to actually download any significant number of updates during normal use. Because the VM can go for weeks without being powered on, it's not unreasonable to expect a number of updates to be available once the VM is powered on.

The workflow I'm looking for is basically, without introducing large delays:

1. "Check for updates"
2. Select the updates I want to install
3. Instruct the system to download and install those updates, followed by shutting down (rather than remaining on)

Ideally, during step 3, if needed, the system would reboot *then* shut down, but this is not required.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/351703/how-can-i-install-updates-and-shut-down-from-the-command-line?rq=1)